# Iterate through all folders in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm trying to apply the same action to all folders contained within a folder in AWS S3. I have an outer folder that contains image files and other inner folders. I want to perform x action on all of the inner folders without having to repeat the command multiple times. What's the best way to iterate through all the inner folders and apply a command to everything within a folder (matching certain parameters, i.e. excluding the image files)?

(I don't think the action itself is super relevant here, but if it's helpful, I'm trying to move all of the files from the inner folder to the outer folder. I already found out how to perform the action individually on one folder, I'm just trying to figure out best practice to perform it on all inner folders within the outer folder at once. The code to do the action once is below.)

`aws s3 mv s3://[PATH]/[source]/ s3://[PATH]/[target]/ --recursive` (where source is the inner folder and target is the outer/container folder)

Comment: I don't think you can indicate multiple source prefixes in a single command.

Comment: So are you wanting to move all objects inside sub-folders to the top-level, regardless of how deep they are in the folder hierarchy? That is, it would effectively remove the hierarchy? (If so, what do you want to do if there are multiple files with the same name?)